# How to fix localhost when it does not refresh and display contents that have been deleted?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am having issues with my app, when I amend the contents, like changing styling, add or delete components, the localhost is still serving old content even after multiple refresh.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think somewhere along a line it is still associated with your backend code. As you can try to restart your system. Or your code editor. Or just try to ctrl + F5 your Browser.